# In R when I am trying to write to an excel file, why am I getting a "no such file or directory" error?

Tags: r, excel

Here are the commands I am using. I want to export this object: "x" into an excel file.

```
> library(xlsx)

> write.xlsx(x, "~/Desktop/project.xlsx")

Error in .jnew("java/io/FileOutputStream", jFile) : 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/Desktop/project.xlsx (No such file or directory)
```

I checked the examples, and this is how the write.xlsx function is used.

Comment: Does the directory "~/Desktop" exist on your system?

Comment: Yes it exists. For some reason it works without the full file path.

Comment: "normalizePath" should force ~ to the full path (might be worth posting as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
write.xlsx(x, file = "~/Desktop/project.xlsx")
```

Somehow this function requires that you specify the variable file.

Comment: There has to be some problem with the path, try to write the complete path avoiding the ~.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify the working directory just type it.
It will save the file using the default working directory.

```
install.packages('xlsx') #if you are using RStudio
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(w, file = "mydata.xlsx")
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more of context for your answer?